# java.io.File.list() giving different order as the folders created sequentially

Tags: java, lexicographic

java.io.File.list() giving different order as the folders created sequentially

While creating the Temporary folders with name as

```
"Temp" + auto-incremented number 
e.g. Temp1, Temp2, Temp3...Temp10, Temp11 and so on.
```

But when I use java.io.File.list() to get the folder list to further processing in order as the folder created,

```
but its giving as Temp1, Temp10, Temp11...Temp19, Temp2, Temp20, Temp21 and so on.

I also tried Arrays.sort(files); but no change in order of folder list
```

Please tell how to get the same order list as the folders created sequentially?

Comment: The default sort would be lexicographic; implement a [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).

Comment: The order in which `File#listFiles` returns `File`s will based on how the OS/native libraries decide the directory listing should be made.

Comment: This is lexicographic ordering of names.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because the way how java compares strings by default in java (lexicographic order).
You can define your own comparator for `File` objects and sort.